# What is this Galaxy At War stuff on the main menu?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I see this when I start up the game. What does it represent? What makes the percentages change?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Galaxy-at-War is Mass Effect 3's multiplayer. That's not the important bit - what you should be interested in instead is the "Galactic Readiness Rating". The idea is that the Reapers are invading, and the Galaxy is not, well, *ready*. How the main storyline resolves depends on the Galactic Readiness Rating when you go on the final mission.

There are three ways to increase Galactic Readiness Rating:

- Winning matches in Mass Effect 3 Multiplayer
- Using one of the Mass Effect 3 iOS apps (there are two: Infiltrator and Datapad)

[Here is where you can find more details on how to increase readiness](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53690/what-are-all-the-ways-to-increase-readiness). Additionally, the [Mass Effect Wikia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Galaxy_at_War) has a little more on it.

That screen represents all aspects of Galactic Readiness, and will default to 50% for all Mass Effect 3 players.

Comment: You had me scared until I read that Wikia page and saw that it's optional!

Comment: Have they indicated if it was possible to attain maximum readiness via single player only?

Comment: @Tristan Yes, it is.

Comment: Phew... I was afraid BioWare (EA) had screwed those of us without Xbox Live/PSN/interwebs access.

Comment: @Sterno I've updated my terminology. Sorry about any confusion.

Comment: @Sterno It's optional in that you don't need to play any of it in order to beat the game, but it does make it significantly easier to get the better endings.