# What are all the ways to increase readiness?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What are all the ways to increase the readiness factor for the war with the Reapers?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Readiness is managed via the [Galaxy at War](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Galaxy_at_War) system and I'll go into the specific ways to earn readiness below:

## Single Player

[**War Assets**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/War_Assets) are the part of Galaxy at War you collect in Single Player. Simply purchase War Assets with in game money to earn varying amounts of readiness, rated by Military Strength. The wiki pages list the [Military Strength](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Galaxy_at_War#Galactic_Readiness) of the various war assets. Some assets require certain conditions to be earned.

War Assets are not Readiness, but instead their effect (Military Strength) is multiplied by Readiness.

## Multiplayer

Playing [Multiplayer](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Multiplayer#Mass_Effect_3:_Galaxy_at_War) earns you various rewards that increase Galactic Readiness, such as [Promoting a character to level 20](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Multiplayer#Promote) or simply completing [missions](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Multiplayer#Missions).

Failure (any mission of any level): 3% Readiness
Bronze Mission (success): 4% Readiness

## Mass Effect: Infiltrator

This iOS game will help you increase Galactic Readiness if you link the games. From EA's press release, via [Cult of Mac](http://www.cultofmac.com/145076/increase-your-galactic-readiness-with-mass-effect-3s-ios-companion-app/):

> Inspired by the deep and immersive Mass Effect 3 universe, in Infiltrator players will help to free prisoners from a hostile Cerberus base and will receive rewards for collecting evidence of Cerberus’ crimes along the way. **Every completed rescue and intelligence discovery in Infiltrator will increase a player’s Galactic Readiness rating directly through the Galaxy at War system in Mass Effect 3**.

It's now available for Android as well: [North America](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.games.meinfiltrator_na) and [everywhere else](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.games.meinfiltrator_row).

## Mass Effect Datapad

[Datapad](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect:_Datapad) is a free iOS app that will allow you to monitor your Galactic Readiness and a minigame which will allow you to slowly increase it. From the Galactic Readiness map you can send select 3 different mission points within each sector which can earn up to a 1% readiness boost for that sector only.  It takes anywhere from 1 hour to 6 hours to earn a point.  You can increase this by getting various power-ups based on points earned playing.

Comment: I'm still trying to find exact numbers, but these are the major actions. Does anyone know the numbers for how much multiplayer mission successes add?

Comment: are the readiness levels for all the sections in the galaxy boosted at the same time or will doing a mission boost the readiness in a particular sector?

Comment: @yx. I've read that if the multiplayer host sets the map selector to random, all sectors get a boost of around 4-5% (on bronze at least). If a specific map is picked, that sector will get a ~15% boost. I haven't tried specifying a map to confirm that yet, though.

Comment: @Brysonic that makes a lot of sense

Comment: @yx. I've been playing random and I'm getting benefits all over AND certain areas are getting concentrated readiness. I'm still trying to work out the numbers.

Comment: Is it just me, or does Galactic Readiness seem like an awfully convenient way for Bioware to get people to redeem/purchase an online code?

Comment: Not really. I played about a dozen or so rounds of GAW over the course of three evenings and my readiness was up to 100%.

Comment: So all those people, like me, who can't use an ios app or can't online multiplayer are basically out of luck in building up our readiness in mass effect 3. This sucks! Why do this in a game that has always been a great single player game??

Comment: if you don't mind updating this, there's a N7 HQ thing on the boiware site now that lets you slowly boost readiness, sort of like the datapad except its web only but with bigger readiness bosts.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell so far, the only ways to increase galactic readiness is through multi-player or either of the iOS Mass Effect 3 games.

You should be able to acquire enough military strength in game to where the readiness doesn't matter.

Comment: can you put specifics?  exactly how much do you get per mission in multiplayer and/or the IOS game

Comment: It's not a set amount per mission; it depends on how many of the bonus round objectives you accomplished, and how fast. Can't say anything about the iOS games.

Answer (score 0):

The only two ways of increasing readiness is by participating in Multiplayer, and by trading in Intel from MEI (Mass Effect: Infiltrator).

MED (Mass Effect: Datapad) is a FREE app which allows you to view your Galaxy at War.
Which in turn is split into 2 things, Strength and Readiness.

I have explained readiness.

Strength is increased by you war assets in single-player, which in turn is multiplied by Readiness.

The better Strength/Readiness you have the better the ending is (Although i don't know what it is I've heard it sucks). Still if it sucks, why get one which sucks more :)

Unfortunately i don't know the specifics of percentages or whatever as i do not have the game yet, however i hope to be the proud owner of a copy soon :D

Answer (score -1):

In multiplayer, play bronze and win to get about 4% added on to your readiness. You get much less if you die.

As for singleplayer, talk to people and do side missions.

Comment: Talking to people in single player has no effect.