# Galaxy readiness and how to increase it

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the ways to increase readiness?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53690/what-are-all-the-ways-to-increase-readiness)

Is there anyway to increase galaxy readiness without playing Galaxy at War, or is this the only way I can increase it?

If I do badly in multiplayer will it lower readiness below 50%?

Comment: You'll probably find what you need on [***What are all the ways to increase readiness?***](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53690/what-are-all-the-ways-to-increase-readiness)

Comment: I concur -- but to answer anyway, you can increase readiness by playing the facebook/iPhone/iPad apps or you can play GAW multiplayer. Readiness will not drop below 50%.